# String[] to ListView in Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to make an list with two TextViews in each line. 
I have String[] like this:

```
public class arrays {
public static String[] PodcastTitle;
public static String[] PodcastURL;
public static String[] PodcastContent;
public static String[] PodcastDate;}
```

I can create a list using this code, but it only allows to put PodcastTitle to list.

```
ListView lv1;
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arrays.PodcastTitle));
```

So my question is how can I make a list that displays PodcastTitle and PodcastDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 as already described.

But you can also use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. To do so you have to make a class like this (override toString):

```
public class Podcast {

    private String title;
    private String date;

    // getter & setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + "\n" + date;
    }
}
```

Make a list of your data instead of your arrays

```
List<Podcast> myData = new ArrayList<Podcast>();
```

And finally the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<Podcast> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Podcast>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myData);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Using this, will just create an empty listview.

Comment: You have to fill the "myData" list with Podcast objects. Podcast pc = new Podcast(); pc.setTitle(...) & pc.setDate(...) and then add the object to the list like myData.add(pc) and then set the adapter

Comment: So what should I write instead of ... in pc.setTitle(...) and pc.setDate(...)

Comment: You should read a java basics tutorial/book. In your Podcast class add setter-methods like "public void setTitle(String title){ this.title = title }" and the same for setDate. I don't know where you get your podcast string arrays from. Instead of "..." you can write "asdf" for testing. Then run the project and see the result. For the rest you should be able to solve it on your own

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` you need `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`, which contains a `TwoLineListItem`.

And instead of `ArrayAdapter` in that case you need to use `SimpleCursorAdapter`. But ideally your data should be structured differently, like a `List<Pair<String, String>>`

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` plus building a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) out of the data would probably work but an `ArrayAdapter` with a `List<Something>` is better here.

Comment: Is it possible to write an example?